# Are PHP Integer array Indexes really numeric?

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, indexing

Consider this example

```
<?php
    $test = array("00"=>"A","B","C","D","E");
    print_r($test);
    echo "<br>";

    echo $test[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $test["0"];
    echo "<br>";

    echo $test["00"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $test[00];
?>
```

Output

> Array ( [00] => A [0] => B [1] => C [2] => D [3] => E )
>
> B
>
> B
>
> A
>
> B

**Q1.** Why is `$test[0]` same as `$test["0"]` whereas `$test[00]` is not same as `$test["00"]`

**Q2.** If the answer to **Q1** is that because `00 = 0` numerically then why does this array have one index as `00` and another as `0`?

**Q3.** If you cannot access `$test["00"]` using `$test[0]` then how do you know which index is numeric and which is string? if both are only numbers

**Edit**

Based on the answers so far, there is another question in my mind. Here goes Question 4.

**Q4.** Why is `if(00==0)` true and `if(07==7)` false? ( for array indexes)

**Q5.**

```
$test = array("00"=>"A","0"=>"B","000"=>"C","0000"=>"D","00000"=>"E");
 echo $test[0];
```

Why the output is **B**, should it not be **A** ? because that is the first element in the array, at 0th position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, one of "the […] *key* casts [that] will occur" is:

> [String](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)s containing valid [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)s will be cast to the [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) type. E.g. the key *"8"* will actually be stored under *8*. On the other hand *"08"* will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.

[[link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)]

Comment: But how can they declare 08 not to be same as 8 in mathematics? 08 should be a valid numeric value of 8 and why is a 00 equal to 0 but a 08 not equal to 8

Comment: this piece of doc says only about casting array indexes and they need to be "valid decimal integer". "0" is 0 but "00" is a string, 00 is an integer 0 so it wont be casted. your example says it all.

Comment: so answer to Q4 is (07==7) is true! but "07"!=7 when it comes to array indexes

Comment: @fsw if your argument was to be taken that 00 is a string then why does PHP evaluate this to `true` ? `if(7=="07")`

Comment: because "07" casted to int normally gives 7 (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) but thing is a bit different when it comes to array indexes (only strings containing valid decimals will be casted)

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ: Mathematical and scientific notations obviously underlie a lot of the notational conventions in programming lanuages, but it shouldn't come as a shock to you that the latter sometimes diverge from the former. For example, in math we might write `1,000,000` for one million, but I don't know of any programming language that allows `,` like that. In science we might write 1.23×10², but I don't know of any programming language that allows either `×` or `²` like that. Similarly -- mathematicians don't have much reason to distinguish `"8"` from `"08"`, but programmers *do*.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks, that absolutely makes sense. But why does PHP in one construct treat 7 same as 07 but in another construct it does not. That is the original confusion

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ: PHP distinguishes `"7"` from `"07"` -- they're different strings -- and since the use of arrays as string-indexed maps is documented and supported, they need to be treated as separate keys. So it's clear that they can't *both* be treated as the integer `7`. The question, then, is how come *either* of them is treated as an integer? I suppose that this design decision was to reduce friction: it's unlikely for someone to want to distinguish `$foo[7]` from `$foo["7"]`, so it's convenient to implicitly convert the latter to the former.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please see question 5? That is the summary of all this debate

Comment: you can do var_dump($test) to see what is really in the array. same rules for getting array element by index apply when setting an element. for example array("0"=>"A", 0=>"B") is actually array with one element "B"

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ: The first element in an `array` expression is put in index `0` only as a default; if you specify a different key, that default is overridden. For example, `array("foo"=>"bar")` will not put `"bar"` under the key `0`, only under the key `"foo"`.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for your time and sharing your valuable knowledge

Comment: As someone once said for one of my questions: `Is that really the only thing you have to complain about in PHP?`

Comment: A more accurate way to say it would be: Strings will be cast to the integer type IF AND ONLY IF casting back would result in the same string. Clearly "0" === (string)(int)"0", but "00" !== (string)(int)"00". So there is only one string per integer value that is considered valid in this context.

Comment: If case you guys are really missing this point? any integer preceding with 0 is an octal representation. So, 07=7 while 08 isn't a valid octal number, so  08!=8.

Comment: @ksg91: Sorry, that's not really correct. It's true that `07` is octal, so means `7`; and therefore that `$test[07]` means `$test[7]`; but the question is about `$test["07"]`, which does *not* mean `$test[7]`.

Answer (score 2):

**Q1.** Because 00 = 0 numerically

**Q2.** Because the index is `"00"` not `00`

Try:

```
$test=array(00=>"A","B","C","D","E");
print_r($test);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
)
*/
```

**Q3.**

```
echo gettype("00");
# string
echo gettype(00);
# integer
echo gettype("0");
# string
echo gettype(0);
# integer
```

From the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.

**Edited after comment**

**Q4.** I think OP's question is essentially why the second and the forth behave differently:

```
php > var_dump("00" === 0);
bool(false)
php > var_dump(00 === 0);
bool(true)
php > var_dump("08" === 8);
bool(false)
php > var_dump(08 === 8);
bool(false)
```

I have no answer yet.

Comment: What is the difference between 00 and "00" if the difference between 0 and "0" is nothing?

Comment: But how can they declare 08 not to be same as 8 in mathematics? 08 should be a valid numeric value of 8 and why is a 00 equal to 0 but a 08 not equal to 8

Comment: Numbers starting with 0 are octal numbers, so 010 == 8.
08 is an invalid octal number and is interpreted as 0, so
`var_dump(08 == 0)` prints `bool(true)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
"anystring" == 0; //true
"0000" == 0;      //true

"0" == 0;      //true
```

Comment: This is false. Any string not starting with a number does evaluate to zero. In other words, your third statement is false.

`("1" == 0);  //false`